# Can't send 2 notifications with noczone php-sdk

Tags: php, android, phpbb

i am using noczone php-sdk to send notifications about new posts in my forum to my mobile , but sometimes if 2 people write a new post , i only get one notification about the first post . i do not get any notification about the other (and yes the other post is saved to the database !)

i am running phpbb and triggering the following code (as it is from noczone)

```
$notifyNoc = new nocZoneNotify();
$notifyNoc->send("New Post $postId - $postTitle");
error_log('Notification sent ! - '.$postId.' '.date());
```

any ideas ?

Comment: Did you delete the first notification? How about the implementation in your Android App? Did you write your own application?

Comment: no . i use their app , and there's no need to delete the notification i guess :s because once i woke up with 4 notifications about new posts

Comment: Notifications in Android work with IDs. So if they internally (in the app) don't change this ID for every message, newer ones does not appear until you delete the first notification. Let me have a look at the noczone app and how they did it.

Comment: noczone.com the app is there and the SDK as well ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can send only 1 notification every 15 seconds for testing.